# MySQL compare timestamp gives error

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a SQL query but I keep getting an error and I have no clue on what could be wrong. I read the manual and searched a lot for it, but I can't get it working.

Query:

```
SELECT appid
FROM steam_app
ORDER BY last_update, appid
WHERE last_update < '2014-10-16 01:01:01'
```

This keeps giving an error SQL Error 1064, SQL syntax.
Now I know the error is on the WHERE line. Because if I remove it, all is well.

Solution: the problem is the order of WHERE and ORDER BY. WHERE should be above ORDER BY.

What I want in the end is a query like:

```
SELECT appid
FROM steam_app
ORDER BY last_update, appid
WHERE last_update < NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

My database:

```
CREATE TABLE `steam_app` (
    `appid` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(128) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `type` VARCHAR(64) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `header_image` VARCHAR(256) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `last_update` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `last_change` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`appid`),
    INDEX `type` (`type`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Sample data

```
INSERT INTO `steam_app` (`appid`, `name`, `type`, `header_image`, `last_update`, `last_change`) VALUES (327400, 'Sid Meier\'s Colonization (Classic)', 'game', 'http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/327400/header.jpg?t=1412883714', '2014-10-16 13:36:37', '2014-10-16 13:36:37');
INSERT INTO `steam_app` (`appid`, `name`, `type`, `header_image`, `last_update`, `last_change`) VALUES (327650, 'May’s Mysteries: The Secret of Dragonville', 'game', 'http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/327650/header.jpg?t=1413366276', '2014-10-16 13:36:37', '2014-10-16 13:36:37');
INSERT INTO `steam_app` (`appid`, `name`, `type`, `header_image`, `last_update`, `last_change`) VALUES (327860, 'Salt', 'game', 'http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/327860/header.jpg?t=1413399075', '2014-10-16 13:31:53', '2014-10-16 13:31:53');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`date_add`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function. Additionally, the `order by` clause comes after the `where` clause:

```
SELECT   last_update, appid
FROM     steam_app
WHERE    last_update < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
ORDER BY last_update, appid
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem was indeed the wrong order of WHERE and ORDER BY